# If $f(x) = y$ holds, does $f(x) = x$ also hold?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What is the difference between functions:

$\ y = |x| $ and $\ x = |x|$

and how these functions are represented in Cartesian Cordinate System?

I think $\ y = |x| $ as capital letter V

and $\ x = |x|$ as whole $y$-axis.

Am I right ?

Comment: Your title doesn't exactly match your question. Also, more context is needed. Are these supposed to be equations in two variables? If so $x = |x|$ just means $x \ge 0$, so the solution to the equation is a half-plane.

Comment: No. this is one variable function. My question is how will graph of function x = |x| look like?

Comment: The expression "$x = |x|$" is not a function. (Neither is the expression $y=|x|$, but most would guess what you mean if you say it is.)

Comment: In 2D plane the graph of |x|=x is just the entire half- plane lying right of the Y axis.

Comment: I put here in question :    x=|x| as whole y-axis

Comment: So what is "x = |x|" if it is not a function?

Comment: @user284901 The point $(1,0)$, for example, satisfies $x=|x|$ (since $1=|1|$), but it's not on the $y$-axis.

Comment: It's an equation, or an equality.

Comment: @ Akiva Weinberger Thank you.

Comment: The equation $y=|x|$ isn't a function either. The function $f$, where $f(x)=|x|$, is a function.

Comment: A function is like a machine that transforms a number into another number. $f$, defined by $f(x)=|x|$, transforms a number into its absolute value.

Comment: y = |x| has two variables.  Its graph of solutions can be represented on the two dimensional x-y plane.  x = |x| has only one variable and its graph of solutions can be graphed on the one dimensional x number line.  It can be represented on the x-y plane but all solutions would include all possible y and be an entire darkened half plane (*not* a 1-dimensional curve).  A function is a collection of pairs (of anything) were each "input" value is paired once with an "output" value.  y=|x| can be thought of as a function as it's solutions are pairs of (x,y) but x=|x| has solutions of singletons.

Comment: @fleablood Thank you for this explanation.

Answer (score 5):

I think your confusion is stemming from a misunderstanding of what an equation really says, and when it defines a function.

When you have an equation with two variables (here $x$ and $y$), it defines a relation between the two.  Sometimes (but not always), this allows you to describe one of the variables as a function of the other.  When you have an equation of one variable, it defines a restriction on what that variable can be.  This defines a set of possible values for that variable - and the set might have just one element, have lots of elements, or be empty.

The equation $y=\lvert x\rvert$ is a statement about two variables.  It states that they must have a certain relation.  It so happens that there are infinitely many pairs of values you could plug in to $y$ and $x$ that have this relation.  Moreover, you can actually choose *any* real value for $x$, and then there will be exactly one value of $y$ making the equation true.  That means this equation defines $y$ as a function of $x$.

The equation $x=\lvert x\rvert$ is a statement about one variable, saying it must satisfy a certain condition.  This condition happens to hold true for all nonnegative real numbers.  But it doesn't define a function, because there's no domain and codomain.  Even if you consider the set of pairs $(x,y)$ that satisfy $x=\lvert x\rvert$, you still won't have a function, because there's more than one possible $y$ value for each $x$.

Comment: I think, my misunderstanding was about equations about two and equations about one variable.